# Integrate Form $(a^2 +u^2)^{3/2}\ du$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I cannot solve that form...

Here, is one of questions asked in that form
Integrate Form $(x^2+ 4)^{3/2}dx$

The answer is $$
(1/4)(x^3+ 10x)(x^2+4)^{1/2}+ 6\ln\ \bigg(\frac{x + (x^2+ 4)^{1/2} }{2}\bigg) + C$$

Edit:
let me show my cal. , please point out where I did wrongly...

I = ∫(x<sup>2</sup>+4)<sup>3/2</sup> dx

Let x = 2 * tany

dx = 2 * sec<sup>2</sup>y dy

I = ∫((4sec<sup>2</sup>y)<sup>1/2</sup>)<sup>3</sup> * (2sec<sup>2</sup>y) dy

= 16 ∫ sec<sup>5</sup>y d(y)

= 16 ∫ sec<sup>3</sup>y d(tany)

= 16 (sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany - 3∫sec<sup>5</sup>y - sec<sup>3</sup>y dy)

Since I = 16 ∫ sec<sup>5</sup>y d(y) AND I = 16 (sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany - 3∫sec<sup>5</sup>y - sec<sup>3</sup>y dy),

I = 16/49 * (sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany + 3∫sec<sup>3</sup> dy)

Since ∫sec<sup>3</sup> dy = 1/2(secy * tany + ln(secy + tany)) + C,

I = 16/49(sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany) + 48/98(secy * tany + ln(secy + tany)) + C

From sub., x/2 = tan y, then, secy = (1/2)(x<sup>2</sup>+4)<sup>1/2</sup>

I = 16/49((1/2)(x<sup>2</sup>+4)<sup>3/2</sup> * x/2) + 48/98((x/4)(x<sup>2</sup>+4)<sup>1/2</sup> + ln((1/2)(x + x<sup>2</sup>+4)<sup>1/2</sup>)) + C

That is the answer I made. However, it is not equal with the model answer....
Please point out my mistakes.... orz

Comment: Is what you are trying to ask here the question of: How do you integrate $\int (x^2 + 4)^{3/2}$? It's unclear if that's what you need...

Comment: Could you explain the trigonometry tag?

Comment: To user37238, because of the trigonmetry substitution..

Comment: Yes, 5xum, I am asking that...

Comment: The error in just before "Since"

Comment: Umm...Sorry, I don't understand...     Does "I = 16 ∫ sec<sup>3</sup>y d(tany)" is correct? If so, I = 16 (sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany - ∫tany d(sec<sup>3</sup>y) ) = 16(sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany - 3∫sec<sup>3</sup>y * tan<sup>2</sup>y d(y) )  = 16(sec<sup>3</sup>y * tany - 3∫sec<sup>5</sup>y - sec<sup>3</sup>y d(y) )

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$I=\int(x^2+4)^{3/2}dx=8\int(\frac{x^2}4+1)^{3/2}dx$

Substitute $x=2\tan \theta$ to get

$I=4\int \sec \theta d\theta=4ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)+c$

And substitute back for $x$.

Comment: Could you go ahead please ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici check the edited version.

Comment: I think that you solved $I=\int(x^2+4)^{-1/2}dx$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici are u kidding me, read it again.\

Comment: I am serious. Using your change of variable, I have to integrate $16 \sec ^5(\theta )$. There is something strange somewhere. I need your help for clarifying. Cheers.

Comment: I = 8∫(x<sup>2</sup>/4 +1)<sup>3/2</sup> dx = 8∫sec<sup>3</sup> dx = 8∫sec<sup>3</sup> * 2sec<sup>2</sup>y dy .... Sorry, I don't understand your step..

Comment: @Hojk. Could you post again your comment ? I cannot read it.Thanks

Comment: sure, I = 8∫(x<sup>2</sup>/4 +1)<sup>3/2</sup> dx = 8∫sec<sup>3</sup> dx = 8∫sec<sup>3</sup> * 2sec<sup>2</sup>y dy .... Sorry, I don't understand your step..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let us take the general form as given in the title of your post.

First, make a change of variable $x=a \sinh (y)$; so, $dx=a \sinh (y) dy$. Then, you need to integrate $a^4 \cosh ^4(y)$ with respect to $y$.

Use the relation between $\cosh ^2(z) $ and $\cosh (2 z)$. You will need to do it twice in order to arrive to something which is simple (remove all povers of $\cosh$). Now, integrate.

I am sure than you can take from here.

Comment: Umm, suppose that indefinite integrals can be solved without sinh and cosh....

Comment: @Hojk. Be sure that it is much simpler.